# maya python random message external calculation

Tags: python, random, maya, countdown

i was trying to get a script which can display random messages every x seconds time.
I ended up having one that kind of works as I need BUT is not ok because Maya freezes while cdoing the countdown .... is there a way do to this is background maybe same external script ?

this is what I have so far

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import random


a= ['message_1','message_2','message_3','message_a','message_b','message_c']

text_mess = random.choice(a)

mc.inViewMessage(amg=random.choice(a), pos='midCenter', fade=True)



# import the time module
import time

# define the countdown func.
def countdown(t):

while t:
    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
    #print(timer, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
  
mc.inViewMessage(amg=random.choice(a), pos='midCenter', fade=True)


# input time in seconds
t = 5

# function call
countdown(int(t))
```

~

thanks in advance
F

Comment: For the duration of your `while` loop, nothing else but the code inside that loop is executing.  I'm not a Maya user, but a quick look at the documentation shows a `MTimerMessage` class that can be used to schedule periodic function calls - that looks like exactly what you need here.

Comment: Totally agree, I am a Maya user and the MTimerMessage is exactly what you need.